# Error handling inside a sort comparator function

Tags: sorting, go

I have the following code to sort a slice of integer strings by the value of the integers. What would be the way to return the err1 and err2 errors in the sortSlice function, in case the error is not nil? The return of the comparator is used by the sort function, so I'm not sure how to return the error.

```
func (o *Object) sortSlice() error {

        sort.Slice(mySlice, func(i, j int) bool {
             numA, err1 := strconv.Atoi(mySlice[i])
             numB, err2 := strconv.Atoi(mySlice[j])
             return numA > numB
        })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to pass through that array once to convert to ints, instead of calling `Atoi` `n^2` times:

```
ints:=make([]int,0,len(mySlice)
for _,x:=range mySlice {
   v, err:=strconv.Atoi(x)
   if err!=nil {
     return err
   }
   ints=append(ints,v)
}
sort.Slice(mySlice,func(i,j int) bool {return ints[i]>ints[j]})
```

In the general case though, you might want to set an error in the outer scope:

```
 var err error
 sort.Slice(mySlice, func(i, j int) bool {
             numA, err1 := strconv.Atoi(mySlice[i])
             if err1!=nil && err==nil {
               err=err1
             }
             numB, err2 := strconv.Atoi(mySlice[j])
             if err2!=nil && err==nil {
               err=err2
             }
             return numA > numB
        })
  return err
```

The above code will capture the first detected error.